# pandas.DataFrame.replace not working with inplace=True

Tags: python, pandas

I have done lots of searching around to try to find if anyone else is having this problem and I cant find a solution (or I'm just bad at looking).

I have a python script which has two functions:

1. Calculate monthly turnover from a cumulative monthly turnover across multiple projects.
2. Alter the code of a project so that any codes ending in the letter R now end in 0.

The first problem I am having is that when the script detects that the code ends in a R it is unsuccessful when replacing it with a 0. Here is the piece of code that does that bellow(All codes are in the format XYZ.1234):

```
if dataset.iloc[i, 1][7:] == "R":
    new_code = dataset.iloc[i, 1][:7] + "0"
    dataset.replace([i, 1], new_code, inplace=True, regex=True)
```

The second problem I am having is with an error that is produced when I run the script. The error, from my understanding, is in reference to the initial part of the script which calculates the difference in the cumulative turnover to get the monthly turnover. The problem that I have wit the error is that it saying that I am trying to pass a string as a float but this shouldn't be happening as the 4th column is always a number. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\tempWork\turnover_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    calcualted_turnover = float(dataset.iloc[i+1, 3]) - float(dataset.iloc[i, 3])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'BAM.1670'
```

These problems could be related but I am not too sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (The turnover figures are not the actuals but placeholders for the script to run)

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
 
dataset = pd.read_csv("turnover.csv")
 
turnover = [0.0]
 
dataset = dataset.fillna(0)
 
for i in range(len(dataset)-1):
    if dataset.iloc[i, 0] == dataset.iloc[i+1, 0]:
        calcualted_turnover = float(dataset.iloc[i+1, 3]) - float(dataset.iloc[i, 3])
    else:
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(dataset.iloc[i+1, 2], "%d/%m/%Y") >= datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=1, day=1):
            calcualted_turnover = dataset.iloc[i+1, 3]
        else:
            calcualted_turnover = 0
    turnover.append(calcualted_turnover)
    if dataset.iloc[i, 1][7:] == "R":
        new_code = dataset.iloc[i, 1][:7] + "0"
        dataset.replace([i, 1], new_code, inplace=True, regex=True)
 
dataset["turnover"] = turnover
 
dataset.to_csv('turnover_complete.csv', index=False)
```

EDIT: apologies, bellow is an example input with the expected output

**Input**

```
Project_Id Project_Number Reporting_Period   Cost To Date
2298       BAM.168R       01/10/2018         100
2298       BAM.168R       01/11/2018         120
2298       BAM.168R       01/12/2018         300
2298       BAM.168R       01/01/2019         550
3015       BOP.1203       01/01/2020         110
3015       BOP.1203       01/02/2020         113
3015       BOP.1203       01/03/2020         190
3015       BOP.1203       01/04/2020         210
```

**Output**

```
Project_Id Project_Number Reporting_Period   Cost To Date   Turnover
2298       BAM.1680       01/10/2018         100            100
2298       BAM.1680       01/11/2018         120            20
2298       BAM.1680       01/12/2018         300            180
2298       BAM.1680       01/01/2019         550            250
3015       BOP.1203       01/01/2020         110            110
3015       BOP.1203       01/02/2020         113            3
3015       BOP.1203       01/03/2020         190            77
3015       BOP.1203       01/04/2020         210            20
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the type explicitly, i.e. `dataset['Project_Number'] = dataset['Project_Number'].astype(str)` ?

Comment: Also, your "example code" is useless, it says there is no 'turnover' etc. Please rewrite the example code so that it might be executed by others.

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: @MichaelO. Sorry, I have updated the example code to hopefully make it more clear. Thank you for suggesting to use the column name, I am quite new to pandas so didnt realise it had this functionality.

Comment: @mozway I have now added an expected output which I hope helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using .iloc to look up individual row and column values, use the power of pandas to work on the entire dataframe at once.  Create new columns as needed, then you can extract data from the new columns.

Error 1:  You can replace by testing all rows at once.  Test whether the column ends with 'R' and if so, append a 'O'.

Error 2:  BAM.1670 is a string.  Is You said the 4th column is a number, so I think you want to work on the 'Cost to Date' column but you are getting the Project_Number column, so your index may be wrong.  Regardless, you can look up values using the column name instead of iloc.  Looks like you need the .shift() function to compare a row to another row, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

```
df.loc[df['Project_Number'].str.endswith('R'), 'Project_Number'] += 'O'

df['calculated turnover'] = df['Cost To Date'] - df['Cost To Date'].shift(1)
# shift(1) = previous row   shift(-1) = next row
```

You may want to do that turnover calculation only if the project number is the same.  Also, you will have a null value for one of the rows because there is no previous row for the first row (or no next row, if you use shift(-1) at the last row).

Comment: Thanks for your help. For error 1, I need to change the letter R to a 0 I hope the new data example clarifies this. For error 2, the iloc only refers to the column index 3 so I don't see how it can pull a project code from the column with index 2. Thank you for your example with the shift function but how will I apply an if statement to that? As you mentioned I need to reset the turnover calculation when it moves to a different project code, which I am doing in the initial code I wrote. Sorry id this was not clear enough this is my first post :)